# "Correct" as an alternative to "Yes"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I'm noticing, whilst watching the George Floyd trial, that a couple of the witnesses are using the word *"Correct"* in response to yes/no questions, as a substitute for *"Yes"*.

Since they're not getting called out on this, is it actually the case that this is acceptable language in a Minnesota courtroom?

Example:

> "Is your co-worker older than you?"
>
> "Correct."

Comment: So far as I know, this usage is idiomatic throughout most of the US.

Comment: Yes, it is is actually the case that this is acceptable language in a Minnesota courtroom, and in any other formal situation. "Correct" has the advantage of being confirmatory and able to answer negative questions Q: "You don't know the accused, do you?" A: "Correct."(i.e. You are correct."), whereas "Yes" could be ambiguous.

Comment: @Greybeard - with your example, in my mind "Yes" would be unambiguous - if the comma is removed from the sentence, "Correct" makes more sense to me than if it (the comma) was left in.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that "correct" might be considered slightly odd, possibly annoying. If the co-worker was actually younger, saying "wrong" or "incorrect" is definitely rude. Both "correct" and "incorrect" imply a statement was made and the truth of It was judged. But in fact no statement was made, a question was asked.

Answer (score 2):

There are English dialects that function without always relying on the words *yes* and *no*.

> Irish has no words that directly translate as "yes" or "no", and
> instead repeats the verb used in the question, negated if necessary,
> to answer. Hiberno-English uses "yes" and "no" less frequently than
> other English dialects as speakers can repeat the verb, positively or
> negatively, instead of (or in redundant addition to) using "yes" or
> "no".
>
> *"Are you coming home soon?" – "I am."*
> *"Is your mobile charged?" – "It isn't."*
>
> This is not limited only to the verb to be: it is also used
> with to have when used as an auxiliary; and, with other verbs, the
> verb to do is used. This is most commonly used for intensification,
> especially in Ulster English.
>
> *"This is strong stuff, so it is."*
> *"We won the game, so we did."*
>
> — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiberno-English#Yes_and_no)

PS. I have no idea about the rules in a Minnesota courtroom.